# Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource; Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a new springboot app and trying to connect with Sql Server. But not able to get the connection, I have been trying lot of solutions over internet but nothing is working.

Below is the exception that I am getting:

```html
2018-08-25 05:55:52 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-08-25 05:56:23 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host RRI2SQLPW14V, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Invalid argument: create. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

2018-08-25 05:56:23 WARN  o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host RRI2SQLPW14V, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Invalid argument: create. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host RRI2SQLPW14V, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Invalid argument: create. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

Below is the configutaion of application.properties:

```html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://RRI2SQLPW14V\\SQL12EEP1:1433
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
```

And below is my pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.oss</groupId>
 <artifactId>OSSIncidentsAutomation</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>ProductionIncidentAutomation</name>
 <description>Automate the production incidents logging in ASM database</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>


</project>
```

Please have a look and help me connecting to DB. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Note: There is no firwall layer to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue in your application.properties file.

Exception clearly says :

```
Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
```

Change datasource url property in a way like this :
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=springbootdb

Source : https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: I tried jdbc:sqlserver://RRI2SQLPW14V\\SQL12EEP1:1433;databaseName=ASM_OSS but it didnt work.

Comment: I think the problem is because of "\\" in your datasource url .
Instead use ip of your database server instead of string "RRI2SQLPW14V\\SQL12EEP1".

Comment: Also, I am using this url : jdbc.url=jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://RRI2SQLPW14V\\SQL12EEP1:1433 in another spring application. Its working fine there.

Comment: As i can see , the exception stating : 

The TCP/IP connection to the host RRI2SQLPW14V, port 1433 has failed.

So, i think spring is not able to take up the full database server url : "RRI2SQLPW14V\\SQL12EEP1" .

Comment: I found somethign strange, When I am changing my runtime environment to different JRE8 instead of JDK1.8, the errors are gone.: Getting below in logs:o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'. So, is it possible that my JDK is faulty?

Comment: Now that you are saying it's working then it can be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see [enter link description here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/connecting-to-named-instances-in-sql-server-from-stash-443548795.html):
Alternatively use the URL below in case the one above does not work:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>;instanceName=<instance_name>;databaseName=<database_name>;
```